# importing from parent package Python - Python import error

Tags: python, python-import, nameerror

I have a directory structure which is as follows

```
controllers/
    __init__.py
    imports.py 
    BLL/
       __init__.py
       foo.py
```

in imports.py I have following line

```
CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY = ndb.Key("Entity", "classroom_student_key")
```

I want to access this CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY  in foo.py

in foo.py I have imported contents of imports like this

```
from controllers.imports import *
```

but when I run the code it gives me error:

```
NameError: global name 'CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY' is not defined
```

both of my **init**.py are empty. I donot want to use CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY as imports.CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY. It should be available with typing just its own name

Comment: Is `ndb` defined in imports.py ? Also, don't do `.. import *` remember the Zen: _Explicit is better than implicit._ -- the only thing i can think of is that `ndb.Key(..)` is failing and the error is being masked.

Comment: yes, it is defined.

Comment: In some of the other files in controller folder I have imported it like 
from imports import * and have accessed CLASSROOM_STUDENT_KEY directly and it does not give any error.

Comment: What is your current directory when you run the program and what is PYTHONPATH?